# Searching for places within a city and in radius around it

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, gis, distance

I'm trying to figure out how to implement searching for locations within a city and in radius around the city. I already have a table with cities:

*cities* table:

`id: INT
name: VARCHAR(20)
lat: FLOAT
lng: FLOAT`

I also have a table with locations.

*locations* table:

`id: INT
city_id: INT
name: VARCHAR(30)
lat: FLOAT
lng: FLOAT`

Typically the coordinates of the city, are for **its center**. This is okay, since when I have a search for locations for a particular city, I can use the city_id in the `locations` table. However, when I have a search within radius **around** the city, the results won't be quite accurate. If the city is relatively small, this won't be a problem. If the city is big, however, and the search is for 10km around the city, most probably the results will be only for the city itself.

My question is, how to handle this situation, **so the results are more accurate**?

What I was thinking is having a *diameter* for each city(which covers the territory of the city) stored in the `cities` table. When I search for places around the city, I would first take the radius(let's name it `cityRadius`) for the target city. Then I would add it to the searched radius(let's say `searchedRadius = 10`).  And then I would execute a query which will search for locations around the city center, within the radius of `cityRadius + searchedRadius`.
I have two problems with this:

1. *I can't find that type of information(radius covering the territory of the city, in particular for cities in Germany).*
2. *It feels kind of hacky. I think there is a better way to do it, but I have a problem finding it.*

My stack is: PHP 7.2, Mysql 5.7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Use `POINT` datatypes and `SPATIAL` indexes. 2. Either get map data that defines your city bounds as a polygon and store that as a `POLYGON` type. 3. Use GIS functions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, I've already read about this, how would the polygon help me in searching within a radius?

Comment: You would either search within the polygon representing the bounds of the city, or look for points X distance away from the polygon, or at the most basic be able to use spatial indexes and GIS functions to do a radius search far more efficiently.

Comment: @Sammitch I will definitely use spatial indexes and GIS functions. However I have problem understanding how I would perform radius search around a polygon?

Comment: What does a 'radius' around a city mean? Tokyo is conservatively 70km across so a 10 km radius around this could include points 80km away from anywhere useful.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, the task is tricky. Like in the case of Tokyo, if its diameter is 70km wide, the proposed solution for searching in radius of 10km towards the center of city, will search only within the city. I guess in theory, it have to expand the polygon(that covers the city) with each N km on each side, if we want to be accurate. But that will be extremely hard to be implemented. I guess I'll have a query which joins the results from within the polygon and the radius around the center of the city. Thanks guys.

Comment: You could always let the user set an arbitrary point [either via location searches, postcode lookup, or clicking on a map] and specifying a radius and/or other criteria. I'd imagine that that would return far more pertinent results regardless of the method used.

Comment: actually, this is a simple distance search and rather straight forward if you are working with *geometries*. query your points table using sth. like `WHERE ST_Distance(<polygon>, <points>) <= <search_distance>`; this will include all points within that distance *to the polygon, i.e. the outline, in all directions* (naturally, this will be a radius search if used with your city center points). `<search_distance>` is usually given in CRS units, so it will be in degrees if used on unprojected geometries! note: I'm no MySQL user, so check the syntax and type dependencies. also, group accordingly.